# In opencart, information page seo keyword doesn't work

Tags: opencart

I create an information page called "we are hiring", and I want to be accessed through http://mystore.com/we-are-hiring.

Supposed it should be done via seo keyword, but it doesn't work for me, anybody know how to do it?

Cheers, Ron

Comment: Are SEO keywords working elsewhere?

Comment: Seems doesn't work anywhere, even for the product.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you have SEO keywords turned on in admin settings (i.e., *System > Settings > Server tab > Use SEO URL's*)
2. Make sure your webserver is Apache and mod_rewrite is installed and enabled.
3. Make sure you have renamed the default `.htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` and that your webserver configuration allows htaccess override.
4. SEO keywords *must be unique*.  Duplicate keywords will break the rewrite.

Comment: It makes sense to me, I will try tonight. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

5. you will have to write the name of you page.
   (in catalog -> information -> your page -> data-> **SEO Keyword**)